# Flex Alert box not showing text after single inverted comma

Tags: apache-flex, escaping, alert

I am launching a flex app (swf) from a JSP page. i am sending a value using flashvars like below.

flashvars.message = '';

This message consists a single inverted comma in between...ex:- L'impression des pages

But when i want to show this message using alert box in flex like Alert.show(message);, it just shows
'L'.  i mean it is not showing complete message. the text after inverted comma is missing....

it will be great if anyone can help me here...

Thanks,
Krish

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> [encodeURIComponent()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#encodeURIComponent%28%29)

to urlEncode your message before passing or simply use **%27(urlEncoded value of ')** in place of ' to see if it works.